# write to shared memory segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, shared-memory, strcpy

all I want to do is just write "hey" to my shared memory, but it gets thrown at that line. very simple code as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#define SHM_SIZE 1024
#define FLAGS IPC_CREAT | 0644
int main(){
    key_t key;
    int shmid;
    if ((key = ftok("ex31.c", 'k')) == -1){ 
        exit(1);}        
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, FLAGS)) == -1) {
            exit(1);}
    char* shmaddr;
    if( shmaddr=shmat(shmid,0,0) == (char*)-1){   //WRONG ARGUMENTS ??
            exit(0); }
    printf("opened shared memory\n");  //gets here
    strcpy(shmaddr, "hey");     //GETS THROWN HERE
    printf("after writing to memory\n"); //never get here
```

the error the debugger gives me is:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x0000000000401966 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe068) at
>   ../ex31.c:449 449         strcpy(shmaddr, "hey");     //GETS THROWN HERE

Comment: Post the output from `ipcs -m`.

Comment: pardon me? there's no output, this is all i have

Comment: Did you get any compilation warnings? Have you read them? They should explain exactly what's wrong.

Comment: `shmaddr=shmat(shmid,0,0) == (char*)-1` --> `(shmaddr=shmat(shmid,0,0)) == (char*)-1`

Comment: Please pause your program before `strcpy`, run `ipcs -m | grep <user name>`  in another shell and post the output of the latter

Comment: @BLUPIXY thank you very much !!!!! solved my problem

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Show a programmer his error, and he will be thankful to you for a day; but show him how to avoid errors, and he will be your competition for your entire life.

Comment: @n.m. *show him how to avoid errors*  **Don't put assignments in conditional clauses.**  `if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, FLAGS)) == -1)` and `if( shmaddr=shmat(shmid,0,0) == (char*)-1)` are *both* bad code - doing that is bug-prone.  Two lines are much clearer, and two lines aren't bug-prone:  `shmid = shmget(...); if ( shmid == -1 )...` won't ever have this problem.

Comment: BTW always the same: take care of compiler warnings...

Comment: @AndrewHenle `if ((foo = bar) == foobar)` is idiomatic C. Beginners should learn it for no other reason than to be able to fluently read other peoples code since it is used everywhere.

Comment: @Art It is not idiomatic, it is dangerous rubbish, because it can easily be turned into `(foo == bar) == foobar` or `foo = foo++` or some other buggy mess. People used to write programs like that in the 70s and 80s. People invented obscure things like "Yoda conditions". And then came the compiler warnings against assignment inside conditions. Programs turned better, bugs disappeared, everyone was happy except Yoda.

Comment: @Art *`if ((foo = bar) == foobar)` is idiomatic C*  The only reason beginners should learn it is so they learn not to use it.  There is absolutely no reason to use a bug-prone construct that tries to stuff too much into one line when exactly equivalent constructs exist that are not bug-prone.  When humans write code, **they write bugs**.  Why on God's good Earth would anyone want to write code in a way that makes it *easier* to introduce bugs?  Human minds are limited in ways computers are not.  What is gained from trying to stuff 4 or 5 operations in one line other than overloading the coder?

Comment: @Lundin It's idiomatic in my world. Kernels, libc, system programs for Unix, etc. I won't argue if it's a good idea or not. But it is used everywhere, still is in modern code. Just checked in some version of Linux I had: `grep 'if ((.* = .*) ==' -r . | wc` gets 830 matches. OpenSSH - 548. gcc - 62, binutils - 173, perl - 74, etc.  It's useful to know if you'll be reading other peoples code which almost everyone will.

Comment: @Art The Unix/Linux world is a special snowflake, since there are such vast amounts of ancient junk code still present in those systems. And the awfully-written Linux kernel certainly didn't improve the situation. It might be that *nix is a lost cause, but that doesn't mean that everyone everywhere else should start writing crap code, just because such code is so common in *nix.

Comment: @Lundin *it is dangerous rubbish* As is C in general. Here, I can have an opinion too.

Comment: @n.m. I don't disagree with that - I can only guess how many people there are that get killed by the C language every day. Couple of thousands every year? This would be why safe subsets like MISRA-C and CERT-C have become so successful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is operator precedence. In the line

```
shmaddr=shmat(shmid,0,0) == (char*)-1)
```

Then the unary `-` operator and the cast operator have the highest precedence, followed by `==`, followed by `=` which has the lowest precedence. So your code turns out to be equal to

```
shmaddr=(shmat(shmid,0,0) == (char*)-1))
```

which is nonsense.

**Assignment inside conditions is very bad programming practice**. Every half-decent compiler will give you a warning if you try it. Apart from operator precedence issues, it is easy to mix up = and ==. Also, the = operator introduces a side effect to the expression, so mixing it with other operators could cause undefined behavior. And perhaps most importantly, putting = inside conditions usually reduce code readability quite a lot.

Your code should be written as:

```
shmaddr = shmat(shmid,0,0);
if(chmaddr  == (char*)-1){
```

It is important to understand that you gain *nothing* by merging these 2 rows into 1. The generated machine code will be identical, apart from the lack of bugs in the above version.